# Twitter bootstrap tooltip on chosen-select not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, jquery-chosen

Did anyone succeed in adding a tooltip on `chosen-select` box?
I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/47/) to demonstrate the problem.

This is the relevant code:

`$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.chosen-select',
    animate: true,
    delay: 400,
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'click hover focus manual',
});`

My guess why this doesn't work, is because the `select` tag has a style of `display: none`.

Comment: "chosen" hide the select element and replace it by a div, so your guess is right. You have to pick another selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you weren't initializing the tooltip properly. You **must** have the `data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!"` attributes on any element to make a tool tip work properly. I also changed which element you were binding the tooltip too.

See fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/50/

**HTML**

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('.chosen-container').tooltip({
    animate: true,
    delay: 400,
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'click hover focus manual'
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle you changed works just fine. I tried to implement it that way but I only get the yellow tooltip under the `chosen-select`. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?